# Bluetooth headset not connecting

Tags: bluetooth

I am new to ubuntu, when I try to connect the headset to my system it connects and right after it automatically disconnects. I am using ubuntu version 22.04 and I have installed Blueman and PulseAudio.

Comment: A lot more information is needed. What is the BT device? Can you connect other devices to this BT, etc.

Comment: Your headset is paired with your computer ?

Comment: It's a boat neckband, yes I can connect it with my windows machine and my phone. It is paired with the system.